# Hudson with Trac

Tags: java, trac, hudson-plugins

Event provider HudsonTracPlugin failed for filters `"Hudson Builds": IOError: Error` getting build info from:

`'http://localhost:8080/hudson/rssAll/api/python?tree=jobs[builds[building,timestamp,duration,result,description,url,fullDisplayName]]': URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10061] >`.

This most likely means you configured a wrong job_url, username, or password.

```
    Event provider HudsonTracPlugin failed for filters "Hudson Builds": IOError: Error getting build info from 'http://localhost:8080/hudson/rssAll/api/python?tree=jobs[builds[building,timestamp,duration,result,description,url,fullDisplayName]]': returned document has unexpected type 'application/atom+xml' (expected 'text/x-python'). The returned text is: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 

<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <title>All all builds</title>
    <link type="text/html" href="http://localhost:8080/hudson/" rel="alternate"/>
    <updated>2013-01-04T09:04:56Z</updated>
    <author>
    <name>Hudson Server</name>  
    </author>
    <id>urn:uuid:903deee0-7bfa-11db-9fe1-0800200c9a66</id>
    <entry>
        <title>tractest12github #9 (broken for a long time)</title>
        <link type="text/html" href="http://localhost:8080/hudson/job/tractest12github/9/" rel="alternate"/><id>tag:hudson.java.net,2013:tractest12github:2013-01-04_18-04-56</id>
        <published>2013-01-04T09:04:56Z</published>
        <updated>2013-01-04T09:04:56Z</updated>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <title>tractest #6 (stable)</title>
        <link type="text/html" href="http://localhost:8080/hudson/job/tractest/6/" rel="alternate"/><id>tag:hudson.java.net,2013:tractest:2013-01-04_18-04-50</id>
        <published>2013-01-04T09:04:50Z</published>
        <updated>2013-01-04T09:04:50Z</updated>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <title>tractest12github #8 (broken for a long time)</title>
        <link type="text/html" href="http://localhost:8080/hudson/job/tractest12github/8/" rel="alternate"/><id>tag:hudson.java.net,2013:tractest12github:2013-01-04_17-52-54</id>
        <published>2013-01-04T08:52:54Z</published>
        <updated>2013-01-04T08:52:54Z</updated>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <title>tractest #5 (stable)</title>
        <link type="text/html" href="http://localhost:8080/hudson/job/tractest/5/" rel="alternate"/><id>tag:hudson.java.net,2013:tractest:2013-01-04_17-52-53</id>
        <published>2013-01-04T08:52:53Z</published>
        <updated>2013-01-04T08:52:53Z</updated>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <title>tractest12github #7 (broken for a long time)</title>
        <link type="text/html" href="http://localhost:8080/hudson/job/tractest12github/7/" rel="alternate"/><id>tag:hudson.java.net,2013:tractest12github:2013-01-04_17-52-06</id>
        <published>2013-01-04T08:52:06Z</published>
        <updated>2013-01-04T08:52:06Z</updated>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <title>tractest12github #6 (broken for a long time)</title>
        <link type="text/html" href="http://localhost:8080/hudson/job/tractest12github/6/" rel="alternate"/><id>tag:hudson.java.net,2013:tractest12github:2013-01-04_17-51-52</id>
        <published>2013-01-04T08:51:52Z</published>
        <updated>2013-01-04T08:51:52Z</updated>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <title>tractest12github #5 (broken for a long time)</title>
        <link type="text/html" href="http://localhost:8080/hudson/job/tractest12github/5/" rel="alternate"/><id>tag:hudson.java.net,2013:tractest12github:2013-01-04_17-51-03</id>
        <published>2013-01-04T08:51:03Z</published>
        <updated>2013-01-04T08:51:03Z</updated>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <title>tractest #4 (stable)</title>
        <link type="text/html" href="http://localhost:8080/hudson/job/tractest/4/" rel="alternate"/><id>tag:hudson.java.net,2013:tractest:2013-01-04_17-50-58</id>
        <published>2013-01-04T08:50:58Z</published>
        <updated>2013-01-04T08:50:58Z</updated>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <title>tractest #3 (stable)</title>
        <link type="text/html" href="http://localhost:8080/hudson/job/tractest/3/" rel="alternate"/><id>tag:hudson.java.net,2013:tractest:2013-01-04_17-50-55</id>
        <published>2013-01-04T08:50:55Z</published>
        <updated>2013-01-04T08:50:55Z</updated>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <title>tractest12github #4 (broken for a long time)</title>
        <link type="text/html" href="http://localhost:8080/hudson/job/tractest12github/4/" rel="alternate"/><id>tag:hudson.java.net,2013:tractest12github:2013-01-03_17-53-04</id>
        <published>2013-01-03T08:53:04Z</published>
        <updated>2013-01-03T08:53:04Z</updated>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <title>tractest #2 (stable)</title>
        <link type="text/html" href="http://localhost:8080/hudson/job/tractest/2/" rel="alternate"/><id>tag:hudson.java.net,2013:tractest:2013-01-03_15-54-59</id>
        <published>2013-01-03T06:54:59Z</published>
        <updated>2013-01-03T06:54:59Z</updated>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <title>tractest12github #3 (broken for a long time)</title>
        <link type="text/html" href="http://localhost:8080/hudson/job/tractest12github/3/" rel="alternate"/><id>tag:hudson.java.net,2013:tractest12github:2013-01-03_15-54-50</id>
        <published>2013-01-03T06:54:50Z</published>
        <updated>2013-01-03T06:54:50Z</updated>
    </entry>
    </feed>   

    Hudson3-3-0 
    Trac 1.0
    HudsonTrac-0.5-py2.7
    Window7 64
```

Answer (score 1):

What is your question?  You'll need to provide more information and some context before we can help you.  An error message alone isn't enough information to figure out your problem.  What were you doing when the problem happened?  Did this work in the past? Has anything been changed/upgraded recently?

From what I'm guessing you're asking, you may find the discussion in this trac-hacks ticket useful: [Ticket #7340 - Authentication failing](http://trac-hacks.org/ticket/7340).

Also, doublecheck your plugin setup and verify that all of your parameters are set correctly (especially '`job_url`').  The error looks like it's getting an RSS feed instead of some other format.  Your URL has "`/rssAll/`" in it, so it makes sense that you're getting an RSS feed.  Chances are, your `job_url` is wrong.  See [the official HudsonTrac documentation](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/HudsonTracPlugin#Configuration) for details about how to configure the plugin.